# How is ActiveRecord scope accessible through object from Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am in a dilemma right now regarding ActiveRecord scope. AFAIU, scope inside model are converted to a class method so they can be invoked only by class not by object.
Say for example if I have a **User** belongs to **Company** association and **Company** has a scope like this:

`scope :blacklisted_companies, -> { ...some code here...}`
I can only call `blacklisted_companies` like `Company.blacklisted_companies`, right?

However, I am able to access it through the associated object from Rails console like this:
`user.company.blacklisted_companies`.

Can someone explain how is this possible?

**EDIT: Clarification as per suggestions, I intend to ask why does it (`user.company.blacklisted_companies`) work in console and not in real code**

Comment: it is related to the method delegation when called on associated objects, so basically everything that is not defined on the user->company association is going to be delegated to the company class itself.

Comment: @potashin your flag is incorrect. This question is about how scopes relate to ActiveRecord Relations and Class methods, nothing to do with preloading. The connected issue might help answer this one but it is fundamentally a different question.

Comment: I am sure you cannot call `blacklisted_companies` on `user.company` just by defining a scope in `Company` model because `user.company` does not return an ActiveRecord Relation but a single object.

Comment: Right but this throws undefined method <blacklisted_companies> error when tried accessing user.company.blacklisted_companies. It worked fine on Rails console. That's what's confusing.

Comment: _"It worked fine on Rails console"_ - What were the exact set of statements that worked?

Comment: user = User.find(1) -> user.company.blacklisted_companies

Comment: Seems like something is off, are you sure it is not `user.companies.blacklisted_companies`? Scopes available on the class, the where chain and though an `has_many` association collection. See the [`scope` documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope).

Comment: I am sure and I just checked again both in the code and in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Reaching through associations in rails makes an ActiveRecord Relation which is a valid target for scopes.

For example: `user.company` from Rails' PoV is equivalent to `Company.where(user: user)`, especially since it's all lazy evaluated.

That's equivalent to a class method, therefore you can call scopes on it.

Edit: OP Changed the question, ignore this answer.

Comment: `user.company` is equivalent to `Company.where(user: user).first`

Comment: Right but this throws undefined method <blacklisted_companies> error when tried accessing user.company.blacklisted_companies. It worked fine on Rails console. That's what's confusing.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I agree, but only once evaluated. Due to laziness it's a relation and it will insert scopes in the middle. Such as `Company.where(user: user).blacklisted_companies.first`

Comment: @steady_daddy If that's the case you have asked the wrong question, Can you open a new question with the real issue in it? Your actual problem could be due to file load order or method overloading or other weirdness unrelated to what you just asked.

I didn't understand why you mentioned the console in your question.

Comment: From the question: "However, I am able to access it through the associated object from Rails console like this: user.company.blacklisted_companies"

Comment: Try using `puts user.company.method(:blacklisted_companies).source_location` in both console and in normal code and see if it's the same.

Your 'however' comment doesn't offer contrast. You have asked 'Why can I use a scope in the console' but you intended to ask 'Why does it work in console and NOT in real code'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question.